# If an object file defines _start and doesn't use any libraries, why do I still need to link it before I can execute it?

Tags: assembly, linker, ld, gnu-assembler, object-files

I have a hello world program:

```
.global _start

.text

_start:
    # write (1, msj, 13)
    mov $1, %rax            # system call 1 is write
    mov $1, %rdi            # file handler 1 is stdout
    mov $message, %rsi      # address of string to output
    mov $13, %rdx           # number of bytes
    syscall

    # exit(0)
    mov $60, %rax           # system call 60 is exit
    xor %rdi, %rdi          # we want to return code 0
    syscall

message:
    .ascii "Hello, world\n"
```

I can assemble this into an object file with:

```
as hello.s -o hello.o
```

This object file is not executable.  When I try to execute it, I get:

```
bash: ./hello.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I need to invoke the linker to make this viable:

```
ld hello.o -o hello
```

At this point, the `hello` program works.  However, the use of the linker here is confusing to me.... I'm not linking in any external libraries!  I seem to just be linking the object file to nothing.

What is the linker doing for such a "self-contained" program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ELF files have different types, like ELFTYPE_EXEC (traditional non-PIE executable) or ELFTYPE_REL (relocatable *object* file, normally with a `.o` filename).

`as` doesn't have a special-case mode that outputs an executable instead of an object file.  There are other assemblers, or at least one: FASM, that do have a special mode to output an ELF executable directly.

Given the ELF object file that `as` produces, you could:

- link it into a simple static executable like you're doing
- link it into a PIE executable
- link it into a dynamic executable, possibly even one that links some `.so` shared libraries; those could have static constructors (init functions) that run before your `_start`.  (For example glibc's `libc.so` does this, which is why it happens to work to call libc functions from `_start` on Linux without manually calling glibc init functions, *if* you dynamically link.)

The `.o` needs to be linked because no absolute address has been chosen for it to be loaded at, to fill in things like your 64-bit absolute immediate in `mov $message, %rsi`.

(If you'd use `lea message(%rip), %rsi` the code would be position-independent but the distance between the `.text` and `.rodata` sections wouldn't be known yet.  Although you put your string right in `.text` so that would get resolved at assemble time if you hadn't chosen the [least efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register) way to get an address into a register, so that would give you a stand-alone block of code+data.  But the most efficient way, `mov $message, %esi`, would also need an absolute (32-bit) address.)

`as` doesn't know what you want to do, and GNU Binutils was primarily written for use by compiler back-ends, so there was no point making `as` more complicated to be able to write an ELF-type `EXEC` file directly since that's what `ld` is for.  This is the Unix philosophy of making small separate tools that do one thing well.

If you want to assemble + link with one command, make a shell script, or use a compiler front-end:

```
gcc -nostdlib -static -no-pie start.s -o static_executable
```